# Fill a GridView column data based on the API response

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am new to ASP.NET. I want to add a column to `GridView` dynamically based on the response of an API

```
id      User     secretcode
1       u1       {response from the API based on the Id value}
2       u1       {response from the API based on the Id value}
3       u1       {response from the API based on the Id value}
4       u1       {response from the API based on the Id value}
5       u1       {response from the API based on the Id value}
```

`id` and `User` are already in my database table (users), so for each returned row, I want to call API to fill my 3rd column i.e. `secretcode`. Basically, I am confused with where to use ForEach loop.

This is rough code on which I am working on:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("Secretcode");
col3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int");
table.Columns.Add(col3);
row[col3] = {response data from API}
gvTest.DataSource = table;
gvTest.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Secretcode");
table.Columns.Add(col);
for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Where 'SomeAPICall()' is calling the API and returning the
    // correct data type. If it is returning an object you may want
    // to convert it before you attach it to the table

    table.Rows[i]["Secretcode"] = SomeAPICall(table.Rows[i]["id"]);
}
gvTest.DataSource = table;
gvTest.DataBind();
```

Or if you're sold on the idea of the foreach loop:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Secretcode");
table.Columns.Add(col);
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    // Where 'SomeAPICall()' is calling the API and returning the
    // correct data type. If it is returning an object you may want
    // to convert it before you attach it to the table

    row["Secretcode"] = SomeAPICall(row["id"]);
}
gvTest.DataSource = table;
gvTest.DataBind();
```

I prefer using for loops generally because often you want to use the same index number on 2 different collections which you can't really do with a foreach loop. In this case though it won't matter.